# Egit Creating a new local branch from remote master

Tags: git, github, egit

I have configured one repository in GitHub "MyRepository"`

In this repository, i have one branch "master"

and in this branch i have one project "Test"

In eclipse i created one local repository, the structured of this repository is as follows.

```
> GitRepo
    --> Branches
          -> Local
              ---> master
    --> Remote Tracking
          -> origin/master
    --> tags
    --> References
    --> Remotes
          --> origin
                --> git@github.com:testusr/myRepository.git
    --> working directory
          --> Test
```

Now suppose i have to work on one defect, so i created on local branch from remote "master" branch like

```
 > GitRepo
        --> Branches
              -> Local
                  --> defect123
                  --> master
```

I switched to branch "defect123" and suppose i working on one file "myFile". Problem occurs over here is that what ever changes i am making in "myFile" in "defect123" branch, it is also reflecting in the "myFile" in "master" branch on the same time.

Why its happening. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean with "it is reflecting in 'master' branch on the same time"?

If you do a checkout of "master" and have uncommited changes in "defect123" this changes will be merged into the "new" checked out working set.

If you commit this changes in "defect123" or stach the changes before checking out "master" you will get a "clean" "master".

Comment: Hi Volker, thanx for your reply. I mean to say from that line is that, whatever changes i make in one file "myFile" while working on branch "defect123", its automatically reflecting in "myFile" on "master" branch without doing any merge. This should not happened, i need to explicitly merge the branch "defect123" to "master" branch for those changes. Will appreciate you reply.

Comment: How do you see the refleting change in master branch? Are you switching between "defect123" and "master" with checkout?

Comment: If you check out a branch (e. g. "defect123") and make changes without commit, these changes don't belong to this branch. They only belong to this branch, if you commit. If you checkout another branch (e.g. "master") having uncommited changes, the changes will be automaticaly merged into the new workspace and will stay there as uncommited changes until you commit.